# logging in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

Is log4r a good option for proper logging in rails app (date time, severity, notification etc?) or is there something else out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this into a ruby file , put the file the /lib folder (Convention) and 'require' it from your environment.

```
require 'active_support'

# Logger class for custom logging format
class CustomLogger < ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger

private
# CustomLogger doesn't define strings for log levels
# so we have to do it ourselves
def severity_string(level)
  case level
    when DEBUG
        :DEBUG
    when INFO
        :INFO
    when WARN
        :WARN
    when ERROR
        :ERROR
    when FATAL
        :FATAL
    else
        :UNKNOWN
  end
end

public
# monkey patch the CustomLogger add method so that
# we can format the log messages the way we want
def add(severity, message = nil, progname = nil, &block)
  return if @level > severity
  message = (message || (block && block.call) || progname).to_s
  # If a newline is necessary then create a new message ending with a newline.
  # Ensures that the original message is not mutated.
  message = "[%5s %s] %s\n" % [severity_string(severity),
                      Time.now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"),
                      message] unless message[-1] == ?\n
  buffer << message
  auto_flush
  message
end

end
```

And these lines in your environment inside the initializer block.

```
config.log_level = ENV['RAILS_ENV']=='development' ?       
ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger::Severity::INFO :     
ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger::Severity::DEBUG
```

Comment: So how do I log stuff? Rails.logger.debug?

Comment: Yeah. But this time when you do a logger debug you get all the detail you wanted. Just make sure you set the environment right in config.log_level

Comment: Shreyas, How would your code change if you wanted to insert the errors into a table? Perhaps assume a model named Log.