# What is the best Rails Logging Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, log4j, log4r

what is the best way of configuring Logging features on a rails project? I'm looking for something like Log4J which is available to Rails. I have found log4r and it's conflicting built in Logger  class and also tried 'Logging' gem and It has some issues configuring as a audit logger. Please let me know your suggestions on this topic  since I'm a beginner on the subject.

I have used below code block in logging.rb and included in environment.rb
But I'm receiving a error on 'returning' keyword as it's deprecated on rails 2.8

### config/environment.rb

```
# Logging
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'logging')

Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
```

### config/logging.rb

```
require 'logging'

# Logging.init is required to avoid 
#   unknown level was given 'info' (ArgumentError)
# or
#   uninitialized constant Logging::MAX_LEVEL_LENGTH (NameError)
# when an Appender or Layout is created BEFORE any Logger is instantiated:
Logging.init :debug, :info, :warn, :error, :fatal

layout = Logging::Layouts::Pattern.new :pattern => "[%d] [%-5l] %m\n"

# Default logfile, history kept for 10 days
default_appender = Logging::Appenders::RollingFile.new 'default', \
  :filename => 'log/default.log', :age => 'daily', :keep => 10, :safe => true, :layout => layout

# Audit logfile, history kept forever
audit_appender = Logging::Appenders::RollingFile.new 'audit', \
  :filename => 'log/audit.log', :age => 'daily', :safe => true, :layout => layout

# Production logfile, history kept forever
prod_appender = Logging::Appenders::RollingFile.new 'prod', \
  :filename => 'log/production.log', :age => 'daily', :safe => true, :layout => layout

DEFAULT_LOGGER = returning Logging::Logger['server'] do |l|
  l.add_appenders default_appender
end
```

Comment: Take a look at my blogpost on how to set up log4r with Rails 3.x, maybe this helps you to get started:  http://blog.mmlac.com/log4r-for-rails/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like this:

**config/logging.rb**

```
require 'logging'

# Logging.init is required to avoid
#   unknown level was given 'info' (ArgumentError)
# or
#   uninitialized constant Logging::MAX_LEVEL_LENGTH (NameError)
# when an Appender or Layout is created BEFORE any Logger is instantiated:
Logging.init :debug, :info, :warn, :error, :fatal

layout = Logging::Layouts::Pattern.new :pattern => "[%d] [%-5l] %m\n"

# Default logfile, history kept for 30 days
default_appender = Logging::Appenders::RollingFile.new 'default', \
  :filename => "log/#{Rails.env}.log", :age => 'daily', :keep => 30, :safe => true, :layout => layout

log = Logging::Logger[:root]
log.add_appenders default_appender
log.level = :info

Rails.logger = log
```

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the following threads:

[Rails Logging API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377822/rails-logging-api)

[logging in rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654827/logging-in-rails-app)

[What's a good logging replacement for rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060455/whats-a-good-logging-replacement-for-rails)